# Consolidating Multiple API Responses into a Single Large File and Writing to an Azure Blob

Tags: c#, rest, azure, blob, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to send data returned from a JSON REST API into flat files on an Azure Storage Blob. Rather than storing the response from each request in a separate file, I would like to consolidate the responses into large batches of 400,000 or so (1 JSON response per line in the file), and then write a single large file (~1 GB) to an Azure blob.

Does anyone know of a good way to handle this in C# code, or perhaps there is a better way to handle it with an existing tool or framework?

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar to this set up, where I log REST API data daily (around 2-3GB) and write them to an external data store.

I ended up using log4net to write the files to a local file, which is nice because it can automatically rotate the files based on something like a date. So you'll end up with 1 file per day.

Then you can setup a job to use the Azure C# SDK to upload files.

(Check out RollingFileAppender for log4net: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html - towards bottom of the page)